# Using Vue-cli with multiple pages, how do i route to the pages within the app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have configured vue-cli3 to build a multiple page application following this guide https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages My app has 2 static pages and I was able to setup vue.config.js as shown below. When I run the application, it loads the index page as expected but I am unable to navigate to the other page.

The index page is served on the base url below
http://localhost:8080/

I've tried the following urls but they do not load the second page
http://localhost:8080/user.html
http://localhost:8080/user
http://localhost:8080/user/user.html

The documentation states that the generated file "output as dist/user.html" but it is unclear how to link to the file programatically or directly from the url.

I also cloned this Vue-cli starter project https://github.com/Plortinus/vue-multiple-pages and noticed that the author got the routing between pages to work by calling a method that invokes `location.assign('../customer/home.html')` But this did not work for me and I'm not sure why.

My vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    pages: {
        index: {
          entry: 'src/visitor/main.js',

          template: 'public/index.html',

          filename: 'index.html',

          title: 'Home Page',

          chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
        },
        user: {
            entry: 'src/user/main.js',

            template: 'public/index.html',

            filename: 'user.html',

            title: 'User Page',

            chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
        }
    }
}
```

Project structure
https://ibb.co/kJ5SqDb

Answer (score 3):

Loading `http://localhost:8080/user.html` is working just fine. Just make sure to specify correct JS chunks for your `user` page - `chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'user']`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the pages configuration from Vue, it's assuming that the app you're working on has server-side routing. This configuration will inject the page-specific JS into the HTML template, and then that template is what gets served to the user via the server.

If you want to use a Vue only configuration and looking for more of a single-page application structure, you don't need to use `pages` and can just use [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/)